# How to get textbox to fill a treeview item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I have a TreeView that has 3 levels in it, driven by a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.  Here is a partial xaml listing:

```
<TreeView
    Name="TreeView"
    ItemsSource="{Binding GTOs}"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <TreeView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <!--  This binding prevents the TreeView from slipping over to the right when an item is clicked.  -->
            <StackPanel MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter, AncestorLevel=1}}" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemsPanel>

    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TreeGTOViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock
                Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown"
                Tag="{Binding Uri}"
                Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

The `Binding` on the `Width` attribute of the TextBlock insures that each `TreeViewItem` assumes the full width of the TreeView container (and not just the width of the text box).  Coupled with the Material Design styling, this produces nice shading effects when the mouse is hovered over a particular item in the tree.

There's only one problem.  While I can get the Width to assume the full width of the TreeViewItem, I can't seem to do the same for the Height.  This means that the user can click near the edge of the TreeView item and see all of the effects as if that item was clicked, but the `MouseDown` event does not fire.

This is the area that *should* be clickable (the dotted red line):

[image]

This is the area that is actually clickable (the outside border of the Text Box):

[image]

I've tried a number of different approaches, including this one:

```
VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
```

and this one:

```
Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}, Path=ActualHeight}"
```

but they either have no effect, or they break the TreeView in unexpected ways.  I think part of the problem is the usual height weirdness of the StackPanel that is being used in the `ItemsPanelTemplate`.

**How do I get the TextBox in each TreeViewItem to assume the height of the actual TreeViewItem?**

Below is an image of the relevant part of the visual tree, from the TreeView down to the clickable Text Box.  The `Ripple` element is a `MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.Ripple` object.

[image]

Comment: Are there any relevant styles that are being applied?  Perhaps a TextBlock style that is keeping the VerticalAlignment to centered?

Comment: @chancea: Almost certainly.  I'm using MaterialDesignInXaml and MahApps.Metro to style the application.  But I've always been able to override those styles locally until now.

Comment: I know you answered yourself already but I think you could've added VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" to the treeview. SelectedItemChanged is the way to go though.

Comment: @J.H.  Would `VerticalContentAlignment` work where `VerticalAlignment` did not?  StackPanel imposes some fairly archaic restrictions on the way you can scale things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a very simple MahApp test project with a treeview and one treeviewitem (no binding).

In the Live Visual Tree, the PART_Header had a VerticalAlignment value of Center. If I changed it to Stretch (using Live Property Explorer), the textblock filled the space vertically.

So, I used the Document Outline in VS to edit a copy of the treeview template. Inside of that, I saw `<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center">` so I decided to set it to Stretch on my TreeView and it seemed to work.

```
<TreeView x:Name="TreeView"
  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved this by going a different route.  Instead of hooking the `MouseDown` event on the Text Block, I'm going to hook the `SelectedItemChanged` event on the Tree View.

```
    <TreeView
        ItemsSource="{Binding GTOs}"
        SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged">
```

The `RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs` of the `SelectedItemChanged` event contains the ViewModel for that particular `TreeViewItem`, which yields the Uri property I need for navigation (I was previously binding this property to the TextBox's Tag property).

The new Event Handler looks like this:

```
private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    dynamic viewModel = e.NewValue;
    var uri = viewModel.Uri;
    (DataContext as TreeViewModel).Navigate(uri);
}
```

Each level of the tree contains a different ViewModel type, but they all have a Uri property, so the `dynamic` binding provides the needed "don't care what type it is" behavior.

I can now remove the `Tag` binding and `MouseDown` event from the TextBlock.

```
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TreeGTOViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <TextBlock
            Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
            Text="{Binding Title}" />
```

and the Tree View items now respond properly, no matter where they are clicked.